# SoapClient: faultcode WSDL

Tags: php, apache, soap, wsdl, soap-client

When I try to use SoapClient:

```
try {
    $client = new SoapClient('http://someurl/somefile.wsdl');
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

I have catch error with:

```
["faultstring"] => "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://someurl/somefile.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://someurl/somefile.wsdl"
["faultcode"] => "WSDL"
```

I can manually download `http://someurl/somefile.wsdl` and can file_get_contents for this file. I try to use it before on different computer and it worked. Possible problem with php or apache settings..

ArchLinux with last updates for php and apache. I tried to enable all php extensions.

Comment: What version is the WDSL file? SoapClient only supports 1.1 and 1.2. If the WSDL is for version 2, you won't be able to use it via SoapClient.

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to get wsdl using `file_get_contents()` in browser?

I had similar issue recently in Archlinux with same faultstring, no matter what wsdl file was used. The same code was working without any problem on other Archlinux machine and Windows XP box.

After some research, it came out that problem arose only when I tried to access the page in browser - script accessed from command line worked as expected. Then I changed the script to download the wsdl file directly, using aforementioned `file_get_contents()` - it gave me a warning `"php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known"`.

Few tutorials (on SO, or this one: http://albertech.net/2011/05/fix-php_network_getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-service-not-known/ ) later I haven't fought off the problem yet. But then I discovered what introduced the issues: I had been running NetworkManager since the installation of Arch (to better handle wireless), and few weeks later I've added mysqld and httpd as last to DAEMONS section in rc.conf - it seems this broke DNS resolution for apache.

Having two solutions (go back to starting servers manually or try other network manager) I've switched to wicd and haven't run into the issue again.